# hql - returning single object instead of list?

Tags: java, hibernate, object, hql

May be a newbie question.

I have a named query which returns only one object. I just wanted to find out if there is one match, does hql return single object instance instead of list as usual?

Googling didn't help.

Comment: you could do count() instead

Comment: I do not want count. I just want that one object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will still return a collection for you to iterate over - but you can use [`uniqueObject`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29) to get a single result instead. That will throw an exception if it turns out there's more than one result.